# how to use $where in mongodb between the same fields in the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My code is the same as

`collSession.find({$where: "this.Prices[0].PGroup_strCode == this.grpCode"`

Using in node.js and mongodb version : 2.4.2
Actaully data is there but its is not giving any result.
Where i m going wrong ?

Comment: what does the schema look like?  are you sure the value of this.Prices[0].PGroup_strCode is what you expect it to be?

Comment: yeah.I m using mongodb native driver.

Comment: In that same function if i put other field without array in that same collection like (this.session == "shan") its is working

Comment: Edit your question to include what one of the documents looks like in Json.

Comment: if you need to use $where then you probably design your schema poorly.  it's not recommended to use $where and you should not need it if you design your documents to match the intended use (i.e. queries you will be running against them).